# Where do I find MySQL commands history on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm aware on Unix, you can find it in $HOME/.mysql_history as detailed in the [official mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-logging.html#mysql-logging-history-file). But I'm using Windows and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Near the top of the same manual page you linked to it says to use the `mysql --syslog` option, and it says on Windows this causes client commands to be sent to the Windows Event Log. I don't use Windows, so I can't test that to confirm, but try it.

Comment: @BillKarwin, yes, but the problem with that is.. I won't be able to see my previous command history since I haven't been using the --syslog option..

Comment: That is correct.